# How to add a String Array item in Java's Switch's Case Value?

Tags: java, arrays, string, switch-statement

We know that since Java 7, Switch's expression can be a String. So I was making an app, where, when a user selects a category he/she will be assigned the concerned department as per the category value. Here's the code:-

```
    public class Selector {
    ///String array to save the departments
    private final static String[] DEPTS = {
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D"
    };

    //String array for the categories
    private final static String[] CATEGORY = {
            "Wind",
            "Air",
            "Fire",
            "Cloud",
            "River",
            "Tree",
            "Abc",
            "Def"
    };

    //return the department when user selects a particular category item from above
    public static String setDepartment(String category) {
        switch(category){
            case "Wind":
                return DEPTS[0];
            case "Air":
                return DEPTS[1];
            case "Fire": case "Cloud": case "River":
                return DEPTS[2];
            case "Tree": case "Abc": case "Def":
                return DEPTS[3];            
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So I was thinking just how I can return the department item using the array index of department, can I use the same thing in the case value, like,

```
case CATEGORY[0]: case CATEGORY[1]: 
     return DEPTS[2];
```

Cause if the category items contain a large string than the cases will become too long to write. If java doesn't allow this, can you suggest some other way so that my code doesn't become cumbersome? Thanks.

Comment: You could use a constant `Map<List<String>, String>` to store your key-value mappings, iterate the `List`s in the keyset to search for any match with the input and return the value associated. Some keys will be 1-sized `List`s.

Comment: Only constant is allowed in `case`.

Comment: Just create a mapping for that task. You can use MAP for an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you use a enum to do that.

```
public class Selector {

  private enum DepartmentCategory = {
    Wind("A"),
    Air("B"),
    Fire("C"),
    Cloud("C"),
    River("C"),
    Tree("D"),
    Abc("D"),
    Def("E");

    private String department;

    DepartmentCategory(String department) {
      this.department = department;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
      return department;
    }
  };
}
```

Now if you are given a department, you can easily get the category by the following code.

```
String category = "Wind";
DepartmentCategory dc = DepartmentCategory.valueOf(category);
dc.getDepartment(); // Returns the department
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of using enum in this situation. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Map<String, String>` to map the category to the department.

Then instead of a switch, you'll have to use `map.get(category)` which will return the department.

You could make it a `Map<String, List<String>>` to map the department to the categories, and do

```
for(String dept : map.keySet())
{
  if(map.get(dept).contains(category))
  {
    return dept;
  }
}
```

Edit: With enums, that works well if there will be no extra departments or categories in the future. A map allows a more dynamic approach. Both work well, if used correctly

Comment: This approach seems more efficient to me. I will try this for sure. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Map<String, String>` to store your associations between department and category rather than a switch statements. It seems like you are trying to use an Array[] for a purpose in which it wasn't intended.

If you use a `Map<String, String>` then you can store your data as follows:

```
Map<String, String> departments = new HashMap<String, String>();
departments.add("Wind", "A")
departments.add("Fire", "B")
departments.add("Fire", "C")
departments.add("River", "C")
departments.add("Cloud", "C")
```

You can then easily retrieve departments names by using the syntax:

```
String category = "Cloud"
String department = departments.get(category)
```

If you want to associate multiple departments you can use `Map<String, List<String>>` to represent a relationship between a type and category and multiple departments.

Traditionally if you think about representing this in a database you would be using a map with an index and an object underneath.

I don't think you want to use Arrays to do this in your case.